# Is there a way to make a clone object move without making it a rigidbody?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, clone

I am currently making a 2D to shoot a projectile which go towards right every time I press ctrl while not making it a rigidbody, but I don't know how to do it.

This is the code of the shooting.

```
 void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
          {  
            Instantiate(projectile,new Vector3(box.transform.position.x, box.transform.position.y+1, box.transform.position.z), projectile.transform.rotation);
                     }
    }
```

This is the code for the projectile.

```
void Update()
    {
this.transform.position+=Vector3.right*speed*Time.deltaTime;
    }
```

I thought it would just go the way I thought it would go, but unexpectedly, the projectiles seemed to be stuck on top of the box without moving right.

Answer (score 0):

try offsetting the position the projectile is instantiated at so it doesn't get stuck on the box

```
Instantiate(projectile,new Vector3(box.transform.position.x + boxWidth, box.transform.position.y + boxHeight, box.transform.position.z + boxDepth), projectile.transform.rotation);
```